# Deleting old relationships and create new ones with the same label in the same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's suppose `Person` and `Car` nodes.

I want **in the same cypher query** to delete all relationships `APerson-[:OWNS]-SomeCar` and inserts new ones.

Basically I had tried this query:

```
MATCH (p:Person {_id: {personId}})
WITH p 
MATCH (c:Car)
WITH p, c 
MATCH p-[r:OWNS]->c 
DELETE r   //deleting all "old" relationships 
WITH c  //a with is expected here by cypher syntax => dummy value that shouldn't impact the remaining of the query
MATCH (p:Person {_id: {personId}}), (c:Car)
WHERE c._id IN {cars} 
WITH p, c
MERGE p-[:OWNS]->c   //merge new ones
```

Parameters passed to the query:  `cars` and `personId`.

However, it results with no new relationships added. 
As if the delete occurs after the merge, and therefore removing ALL relationships completely.

Any way to do it in the same query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Does this query do what you want?

```
MATCH (p:Person {_id: {personId}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:OWNS]->(:Car)
DELETE r
WITH p
MATCH (c:Car)
WHERE c._id IN {cars}
MERGE p-[:OWNS]->c;
```

This query uses `OPTIONAL MATCH` to allow the entire query to be processed even if there is no existing `OWNS` relationship. (A non-optional `MATCH` clause would abort the entire query if it failed to find a match.)

It also re-uses the matched `Person` node to avoid a second match attempt.

In addition, my query specifies the only required `WITH` clause. A write clause (like `DELETE`) cannot be followed by a read clause (like `MATCH`) unless there is a `WITH` clause between them.

Comment: What is the difference with mine ?

Comment: Actually, the original non-optional `MATCH` clause was the issue. It would abort the entire query if if failed to match.