# Convert Neo4j query in c# using optinal match and merge

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

Im trying to convert a Neo4j Cypher query that works in Neo4j Desktop but when im trying to use it on c# it doesn't work, can someone help me?

C# query:

```
        var type = typeof(T).Name;

        var client = Graph.GetClient();

        client.Cypher
            .Match("(location:Location")
            .Where((Location location) => location.GeoNameId == entityGiven.GeoNameId)
            .OptionalMatch("()-[r:HAS]->(location)")
            .Delete("r")
            .With("l")
            .Match("admin:" + type + ")")
            .Where((Admin admin) => admin.GeoNameId == geoNameId)
            .Merge("(admin)-[:HAS]->(location)")
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Neo4j Cypher Query:

```
MATCH (l:Location {GeoNameId: 9410021})
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r:HAS]->(l)
DELETE r
WITH l
MATCH (a:Admin2 {GeoNameId:  2367567})
MERGE (a)-[:HAS]->(l);
```

**Already got it just missed a little things that's the solution:**

```
            .Match("(location:Location)")
            .Where((Location location) => location.GeoNameId == entityGiven.GeoNameId)
            .OptionalMatch("()-[r:HAS]->(location)")
            .Delete("r")
            .With("location")
            .Match("(admin:" + type + ")")
            .Where((Admin admin) => admin.GeoNameId == geoNameId)
            .Merge("(admin)-[:HAS]->(location)")
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Does your code produce the desired query? Should not .Match("(location:Location") include another ): .Match("(location:Location)")

Comment: David you're right mate, thanks a alot, already fixed it and worked

Comment: Some things are simple!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
                   form.formHeader .table1 {
                  display: inline-block;
                  width:33%;
                  float:left;
                }
                form.formHeader .table2  {
                  display: inline-block;
                  width:33%;
                  float:left;
                }

               form.formHeader .table3  {
                  display: inline-block;
                  width:34%;
                  float:left;
                }
    
                      form.formHeader{}

                  form.formHeader .inlineTable {
                            display: inline-block;
                            border: none !important;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                font-size: 10px;
                            }

                form.formHeader #bang {
                        border: none !important;
                        width: 100 %;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            font-size: 10px;
                        }

                form.formHeader #bang1 {
                        border: none !important;  
                    width: 100%;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    font-size: 10px;
                  }

                form.formHeader #bang2 {
                    border: none !important;  
                    width: 100%;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    font-size: 10px;
                  }
  
                 form.formHeader .inlineTable th, form.formHeader .inlineTable td {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
                    padding: 5px;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                  }

                form.formHeader .inlineTable th
                {
                    text-align: left;
                }

               form.formHeader  .inlineTable  td
                {
                    text-align: right;
                }
    
                    .generalInfo {
                    width: 100%;
                    background: aliceblue;
                    border-top: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    height: 23px;
                    padding-top: 4px;
                }
    .pdfForm {
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px rgba(50,50,50,0.75); 
                }
    
                    #create_pdf {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    background-color: white;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    text-align: center;
                    color: #0271B6;
                    padding: 7px 17px 5px;
                    height: 35px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border: 1px solid rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.59);
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                    display: block;
                    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form pdfForm" id="pdfFormID" style="max-width: none;">
   <table style = "width: 100%;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="width: 40%; text-align:left"> <img src="https://tercersector.org.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Logo-MetroGAS-.jpg" alt="Metrogras" width="120" height="42" id="imgMetro"></th>
   <th style = "text-align: right; width: 30%; font-size: 12px;"><br/><br/> Engeniero: RAMOS PEDRO </th>
   <th style = "text-align: right; width: 30%; font-size: 12px;"> Fecha: Data de Hoje <br/><br/> Identificación del boleto: DA2020030_m1 </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
   </table>
   <div id="insertInfoHere" class="generalInfo"> Informacion General</div>
   <div style = "width:100%">
                  <div class="table1">
                   <table class="inlineTable" id="bang">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <td>Bill Gates</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 854</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 855</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
                  <div class="table2">
                   <table class="inlineTable" id="bang1">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <td>Bill Gates</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 854</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 855</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
                  <div class="table3">
                   <table class="inlineTable" id="bang2">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <td>Bill Gates</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 854</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Telephone:</th>
                        <td>555 77 855</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
                </div>
</form> 
<input type="button" id="create_pdf" onclick ="generatePDF()" value= "Generar PDF">;

    
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  form.pdfForm .table1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
  }
  form.pdfForm .table2  {
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
  }

  form.pdfForm .table3  {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width:34%;
    float:left;
  }
    
  form.pdfForm .inlineTable {
    border: none !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  form.pdfForm .inlineTable th, form.pdfForm .inlineTable td {
    border-top: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  form.pdfForm .inlineTable th
  {
    text-align: left;
  }

  form.pdfForm  .inlineTable  td
  {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .generalInfo {
    width: 100%;
    background: aliceblue;
    border-top: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 4px;
  }
  
  .propertyInfo {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    height: 18px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-size:12px;
    background: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  .pdfForm {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px rgba(50,50,50,0.75); 
  }

  #create_pdf {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0271B6;
    padding: 7px 17px 5px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.59);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: block;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
  form.pdfForm .tableLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
  
  form.pdfForm .tableRight  {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
  }
  
  .padding-left-5px {
      padding-left: 5px;
  }
      
  .propertyTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  }

  .propertyTable td, .propertyTable th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form pdfForm" id="pdfFormID" style="max-width: none;">
   <table style = "width: 100%;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="width: 40%; text-align:left"> <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArchivo%3AMetrogas_logo.svg&psig=AOvVaw0Wnj3MMsGi3PaaqOcjWltm&ust=1588672013230000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLiw_cr2mekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI" alt="Metrogras" width="120" height="42" id="imgMetro"></th>
   <th style = "text-align: right; width: 30%; font-size: 12px;"><br/><br/> Engeniero: RAMOS PEDRO </th>
   <th style = "text-align: right; width: 30%; font-size: 12px;"> Fecha: Data de Hoje <br/><br/> Identificación del boleto: DA2020030_m1 </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
   </table>
   <div class="generalInfo"> Informacion General</div>
  <div class="table1">
    <table class="inlineTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Tipo de Tarea:</th>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Comentario:</th>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Motivo:</th>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table2">
    <table class="inlineTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Estado:</th>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Orden de Servicio:</th>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Ítem de Línea:</th>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table3">
    <table class="inlineTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Inicio:</th>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Finalización:</th>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Duración:</th>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="generalInfo"> Formulario Nombre</div>
  <div class="tableLeft">
    <table class="inlineTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRight">
    <table class="inlineTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Propriedade Nombre:</th>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="propertyInfo"> <div class="padding-left-5px">Propriedade Nombre</div></div>
  <table class="propertyTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
  

</form> 
<input type="button" id="create_pdf" onclick ="generatePDF()" value= "Generar PDF">

    
 

</body>
</html>
```